# can you change a yaml by a node

Tags: ros, gazebo, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI
I am working with the drc robot, it comes with PID controller on each of the joints. The parameters of each PID are all in a yaml format file. I would want to change some of those parameters while those controllers are running. How should I do it?
Thanks all.
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47662/can-you-change-a-yaml-by-a-node/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

YAML configurations are uploaded on the parameter server and you can change them using `rosparam set <parameter name> <value>` from the command line. roscpp and rospy also provide methods to change the values of parameters. However, just changing PID parameters will not have any effect unless you restart the corresponding controller. I don't know how the controller architecture on your robot looks like, so I cannot provide any information on how to achieve that.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-11-07**:
I am working on the Drc robot of Darpa. All the joints come with a pid but i would like to change some of them.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-11-24**:
For DRC specific questions I suggest you use the DRC forums.

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-11-27**:
Lorenz - does it mean that when I do it my robot will be without controllers for a moment?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-27**:
Since I do not know your platform, all I can say is that it depends on the implementation o your controller framework. On the PR2 for instance, controller switching is possible almost without a delay.